# Fuzzy logic and Truth Values

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, logic

Let's say we have the three-valued fuzzy logic with truth-values from $Q =$ {$0, 1/2, 1$}. My question is can the set of {$∧, ∨, ¬, ⊕, ↔,→$} plus the three truth-values be used to generate all functions from $Q^2 → Q$?

Operators are defined:

$p ∧ q = min${$p, q$};

$p ∨ q = max${$p, q$};

$¬p = 1 − p$;

$p → q = min${$1 + q − p, 1$};

$p ↔ q = min${$1 + p − q, 1 + q − p$};

$p ⊕ q = min${$p + q, 2 − p − q$}.

Comment: How are these operators defined? For example, what would be $\frac{1}{2} \land \frac{1}{2}$? Etc.

Comment: Suppose they are defined this way:p ∧ q = min{p, q};
p ∨ q = max{p, q};
¬p = 1 − p;
p → q = min{1 + q − p, 1};
p ↔ q = min{1 + p − q, 1 + q − p};
p ⊕ q = min{p + q, 2 − p − q}.

Comment: I always thought that $p\land q$ means $p$ *and* $q$, with $p\lor q$ meaning $p$ *or* $q$.

Answer (score 2):

Without using the truth-values as constants, you can't capture any function that returns the value of $\frac{1}{2}$ for one or more of the cases where all arguments have a value of $0$ or $1$, since no matter which and how many of the operators you use, the result will always be $0$ or $1$

But if you have the truth-functions as constants, then yes, you can capture any function (with any number of variables) with these. In fact, all you need is the constant $\frac{1}{2}$

To see why, let's use the same strategy as we do with boolean logic: take any truth-function, put it on a truth-table, and generate terms for each row that in the end we all disjunct together. This time, though, we need to capture the rows where it has a value of $1$ as well as the rows where it has a truth-value of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Now, to pick out a specific row, we want to able to say things like 'the row where $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and $q = 1$'. OK, so what we really want is an expression that returns $1$ where $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and returns $0$ otherwise, and same for $p=1$ and $p=0$

Well, for $p=\frac{1}{2}$ we can use $p \leftrightarrow \neg p$, for $p=1$ we can use $\neg (p \rightarrow \neg p)$, and for $p =0$ we can use $\neg (\neg p \rightarrow \neg p)$

OK, so with that, and using the conjunction to do this for all variables, we can pick out exactly the row we want, i.e. we get an expression that returns a $1$ for that row, and no other rows. Then, when the truth-function for that row is $\frac{1}{2}$, we simply conjunct that expression with $\frac{1}{2}$. And finally, we disjunct all the resulting expressions together.

Example. Suppose we want to capture the following function:

\begin{array}{cc|c}
p&q&f(p,q)\\
\hline
1&1&0\\
1&\frac{1}{2}&0\\
1&0&1\\
\frac{1}{2}&1&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\
\frac{1}{2}&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
0&\frac{1}{2}&0\\
0&0&\frac{1}{2}\\
\end{array}

Then using the method as described above we get the expression:

$$(\neg (p \rightarrow \neg p) \land \neg (\neg q \rightarrow q)) \lor $$

$$((p \leftrightarrow \neg p) \land \neg (q \rightarrow \neg q) \land \frac{1}{2}) \lor $$

$$((p \leftrightarrow \neg p) \land \neg (\neg q \rightarrow q)) \lor$$

$$(\neg (\neg p \rightarrow p) \land \neg (\neg q \rightarrow q) \land \frac{1}{2})$$

Comment: Ahh when you say the case where both arguments have a value of 0 or 1, what arguments are your referring to like for example..?

Comment: @Homaniac I mean that when you have a function $f(P,Q)$, the arguments would be $P$ and $Q$ ... but on another note, I just realized that you said that you have the three truth-values to work with as well ... as constants you mean?  Becuase if so, then my answer is certainly not correct, for then you could simply use the $\frac{1}{2}$ constant value to produce $\frac{1}{2}$'s also in the cases where both argument are both $0$ or $1$ ....

Comment: Well yes I think we are allowed to use the 1/2 constant as well, but what does it mean to generate ALL functions from $Q^2$ to $Q$ even..? So it is possible then?

Comment: @Homaniac yes, with the constant $\frac{1}{2}$ it becomes expressively complete ... let me edit my post ...

Comment: Ah how do we know all we need is  ¬, →, and the constant 1/2?

Comment: @Homaniac OK, I explained in my answer now .... right now I use $\frac{1}{2}$, $\neg$, $\rightarrow$, $\leftrightarrow$, $\land$, and $\lor$. I know the $\leftrightarrow$ can be rewritten using the usual conjunction of tow conditionals, so that one is not needed. Likewise, one of the $\land$ and $\lor$ can be rewritten using the other one and $\neg$ by the typical DeMorgan, so we don't need both of those ... still trying to figure out if the $\rightarrow$ can be rewritten in twrms of $\neg$ and $\lor$ or vice versa ....